# <link rel="preload" as="script" href=".."> vs <script src="..." />

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between:

```
<link rel="preload" as="script" href="..">
```

and

```
<script src="..." />
```

Is **rel="preload"** really needed in the first example?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types/preload

Answer (score 2):

The first one asks the browser to download a script, but not execute it.
In case it is requested somehow, the browser can simply load it from cache.

The second one downloads a script and executes its content.

If you use `link`, you need to fill `rel`  as `preload`. You can't embed js via link.
With `link` you ask the browser to cache something, because you might need it soon.

Comment: Correct Answer.